# Filtrar por los que no asistieron en una fecha determinada

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo 2 tablas

Control:

- id_personal
- fecha
- hora
- id_tienda

Personal:

- id_personal
- nombre
- apellidos

Necesito saber quien no se registro y en que fecha, ya sea por una consulta SQL

En la tabla control se hace el registro diario de quien se registra, o sea que no se registran los que no asisten (obviamente)
En la tabla Personal se encuentran todos los empleados registrados.

Mi idea es comparar el id_personal de ambas tablas, 
buscar en la tabla control el id_personal que que es igual a id_persona de la tabla Personal, y si no se encuentra guardar en una nueva tabla los que no se encontraron y la fecha en que no asistieron en la siguiente tabla

asistencia:

- id_personal
- fecha

pero la fecha se registra con el formato `dd/mm/yyyy`
y es tipo `varchar`, necesito una consulta, ya se con laravel o simplemente sql.

GRACIAS

Esto es una consulta en Laravel que tengo hecho

```
esta me da los que asistieron nadamas
 $asistencias = DB::connection('mysql3')
        ->table('personal')
        ->select('id_personal')
        ->join('control','control.id_personal', '=', 'personal.id_personal')
        ->select( 'personal.nombre','personal.apellidos', 'control.hora','control.id_tienda','control.fecha','control.id_personal')
        ->where('fecha','LIKE',"%$fecha%")
        ->paginate(200);

Esto fue un intento de saber las faltas
    $faltas = DB::connection('mysql3')
            ->table('control as a')
             ->select('id_personal')
            ->join('personal as b',function($join){
                $join->on('a.id_personal','!=','b.id_personal');
               ->whereNotIn('fecha','LIKE',"%$fecha%");
            })    
            ->select("a.id_personal","b.nombre")
            ->where('fecha','LIKE',"%$fecha%")
            ->get();

Y esta es otra prueba de SQL que hice

    ->select('SELECT t1.id_personal
             FROM control t1 INNER JOIN personal t2 ON t1.id_personal=t2.id_personal
             WHERE not fecha LIKE '%$fecha%' ');
```

Comment: ¿Cuál manejador de base de datos usas? La sintaxis varia entre uno y otro. ¿Tienes alguna tabla de calendario o la podrías crear?

Comment: Estoy Utilizando Mysql, solo tengo esas 2 tablas

Comment: Esa consulta que muestras en ambos casos ¿qué devuelve?

Comment: Solo me devuelve los que si asistieron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Parte 1**

A nivel de SQL la consulta queda con el uso de `WHERE NOT EXISTS` para identificar aquel personal cuyo `id` no existe en la tabla de `control` como llave foránea ya que existe para retornar solo 2 posibles valores: false o true.

Hacemos uso del operador `AND` para indicar que también busque por la fecha

**Consulta de ejemplo**

```
SELECT personal.nombre,
       personal.apellidos
FROM personal 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT control.id_personal 
                 FROM control 
                 WHERE personal.id_personal = control.id_personal 
                 AND control.fecha = "2019-01-26");
```

**Parte 2**

Ahora a nivel de *Laravel* considera que deberías tener los siguientes modelos creados:

- Personal
- Control

Dentro del Modelo Personal deberás declarar lo siguiente:

```
protected $table = "personal";
protected $primaryKey = "id_personal";
public function control()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Control::class, 'id_personal');
}
```

Dentro del modelo Control deberás declarar lo siguiente:

```
protected $table = "control";
protected $primaryKey = "id_personal";
public function personal()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Personal::class);
}
```

Finalmente para el caso de la consulta nos auxiliamos del método `whereDoesntHave` el cual nos ayudará a filtrar de un modelo los datos que no existan con el método que le pasemos como argumento producto de haber trabajado con las relaciones de Laravel para pasar una función anónima para indicar parámetros extra en nuestra consulta así:

```
$data = Personal::whereDoesntHave('control', function($query) {
            $query->whereDate('control.fecha', '2019-01-26');
        })->get();
```

**Observaciones**

- Como tu tabla no esta en plural entonces debemos en cada modelo declarar una propiedad que igualamos con el nombre de cada una
- Como las llaves foráneas son distintas a las esperadas por Laravel, entonces también debemos declarar una propiedad privada a la cual igualamos con el nombre en cuestión.

> En ambos casos tanto a nivel de SQL como de Eloquent en Laravel nos va a retornar de acuerdo con una fecha el nombre y apellidos de aquel usuario que no asistió y que no esta registrado en la tabla de control

**Referencias**

- [MySQL WHERE NOT EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
- [Laravel whereDoesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)
- [Laravel relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Comment: Dudo mucho que se inserten datos en la tabla de control con fecha NULL. En todo caso, no se podría saber en cual fecha no asistió.

Comment: Eso es correcto

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar este problema, necesitas tener una tabla de calendario para obtener todas las fechas posibles y así poder detectar las faltantes. Una vez que tengas la tabla de calendario, se hacen todas las combinaciones posibles con los empleados y se limitan las fechas (como fechas, no como cadenas) para evitar un resultado enorme. A ese producto cartesiano, le quitas todas las filas que se encuentren en la tabla de control.

Al final, queda una consulta similar a esta:

```
SELECT *
FROM Personal p
CROSS JOIN Calendario cal
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT *
                  FROM Control co
                  WHERE p.id_personal = co.id_personal
                  AND   cal.fecha_dmy = co.fecha);
```